# Joint density and univariate time series models

Tags: time-series, density-function, univariate

Is the picture below an example of univariate time series model since I am observing the same random variable just at different time points?

[image]Can joint density be used to explain univariate time series models since we use the same term joint density for models where the same random variable is just observed at different time points or do we need observations of multiple variables (X, Y) over different time points?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Time series just means there is a temporal structure in the correlation between adjacent observations. Time series does not defy the general rules of probability. If you have the joint distribution of a time series, that will give you complete information about the data.

Comment: There are $n$ random variables in your time series, so it is not really univariate

Comment: Can I use a joint density function to describe any univariate time series ?

Comment: @Shetu yes, although a joint density isn’t just handed to you. You’d have to build the model yourself. Computing a joint density is straightforward in the iid case but times series aren’t iid. You might want to look at the [probabilistic chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)).